# Set up jack2 server on ubuntu 15

Tags: sound, jack, lmms

I'm trying to make my lmms 1.1.3 installaton work with jack2, but I have no idea which packages I should install and what should configure to make it work. I've tried to install jackd2 and qjckctl packages, jack server seems to start with lmms, but I have no sound and log says that it cant allocate memory.

Comment: Can you kindly include the entire contents of the JACK server log window?